# Significance of partition containment in representation theory of $\operatorname{GL}_n$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, schur-functions

I'm working on a Schur positivity problem and I came across a series of Schur polynomials (all in $n$ variables) whose indexing partitions are (conjecturally) contained in one of some given set of partitions. In other words, there are some $\lambda_i$ which are given, and for every $\mu$ that I produce, I've noticed that $\mu \subseteq \lambda_i$ for some $i$.

I'd like to know if there is any representation-theoretic significance to this containment, in terms of the corresponding irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n$.

Obviously they're not "subreps" but is there an answer like this that one can give?

Comment: Maybe a (Gelfand--Tsetlin-style) restriction to an irrep for a subgroup isomorphic to $GL_k$ with $k=|\mu|<n$?

Comment: Sounds like some type of vanishing property also. Shifted Schur functions are defined in a very nice manner by stating that they should vanish when evaluated at smaller partitions. Perhaps what you see is related?

Answer (score 5):

I am not quite sure what you are after. Maybe this: Let $V_\lambda$ be the polynomial irrep of $GL(n)$ corresponding to the partition $\lambda$. Then $\mu$ is contained in $\lambda$ if and only if $V_\lambda$ occurs in $V_\mu\otimes V_\tau$ for some $\tau$. This can be seen in a number of ways, e.g., the Pieri rule, the Littlewood-Richardson rule, or the (non-)vanishing of the skew Schur function $s_{\lambda/\mu}$. Using the latter method:
$$
\mu\subseteq\lambda \Leftrightarrow s_{\lambda/\mu}\ne0
\Leftrightarrow\exists\tau:\langle s_{\lambda/\mu},s_\tau\rangle\ne0
\Leftrightarrow \exists\tau:\langle s_\lambda,s_\mu s_\tau\rangle\ne0
\Leftrightarrow \exists\tau:V_\lambda\subseteq V_\mu\otimes V_\tau
$$

Comment: I don't think so. If the $\mu$-weight space of $V_\lambda$ is nonzero then $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are partitions of the same degree, so they can't be contained in each other unless they are equal. The weight spaces are controlled by the dominance order  not the containment order.

Comment: Of course; sorry, silly mistake! I was thinking about the wrong partial order.